# How to store fetched links (from using Beatuiful Soup) into a list in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This may be a duplicate, but I've searched around and can't find anything. Anyways, I have a for loop that searches for the correct links to grab with the code below.

```
for a in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile(r"url_that_I'm_using")):
  Links = a["href"]
  print(Links)
```

The output of this are multiple links as shown below

```
Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
Etc
```

How would I be able to take the output above and link it to a variable that if called out via Links[0], it would give Link 1? Or if I had called out Links[1], it would output Link 2 and so on.

Comment: Beautiful Soup*

Comment: `links = []` before your for loop then `links.append(a["href"])` within the for loop.

Comment: Update your code above with what you've tried.

Comment: `var=[a['href'] for a in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile(r"url_that_I'm_using"))] ` you can use list comphresion to create list with all link and then acess using list index

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
Links = [a["href"] for a in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile(r"url_that_I'm_using"))]
```